# Modify grade table in exam class so that all questions have the same points

Tags: macros, exam, gradetable

Is it possible to manually change the individual question points so that all questions have the same points?

I don't want to allocate a specific point in `\question[]`.?

I know how to force the total points, but I can't find information on how to manually change all the points in all questions to the same point.

My MWE

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{questions}
\question This is Q1 with no marks.
\question This is Q2 with no marks.
\question This is Q3 with no marks.
\end{questions}

\settabletotalpoints{3}\gradetable % I know how to change the total points in a grade table.
\end{document}
```

Current Output:
[image: Output with all 0's]

Desired Output:
[image: Output with all 1's manually added]

Comment: Without knowing any details about the used class/package, I think it should be possible to simply create your own question macro that evaluates to the original `\question` macro with the appropriate points set...

Comment: @raven I'm not sure how to since there is no information on setting individual question total points in the documentaiton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [package manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/exam?lang=de) you can format the display of the points for each question. It seems that is what you would like to achieve because Q1 has no points displayed, but you would like to allocate one point. So lets simply remove it by using an empty `\pointformat{}`. I've assigned one point to each question this way we can get rid of the manual update of the total points table.

Additionally, I've added a fourth question to demonstrate how you get the point counter back. Have a look at the [package manual, pg. 26 ff.](https://ctan.org/pkg/exam?lang=de) to find out how to format the points display according to your desire.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{questions}
\pointformat{}
\question[1] This is Q1 with no marks.
\question[1] This is Q2 with no marks.
\question[1] This is Q3 with no marks.
\pointformat{\fbox{\thepoints}}
\question[4] This is Q4 with  marks.
\end{questions}

\gradetable % I know how to change the total points in a grade table.
\end{document}
```

And this it what it looks like:

[image: Question - without points using the exam class]

In case you are undecided, if it should be 1 point for questions that have *no mark* you could use a variable as placeholder.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\nopoints}{1}
\begin{questions}
\pointformat{}
\question[\nopoints] This is Q1 with no marks.
\question[\nopoints] This is Q2 with no marks.
\question[\nopoints]
\pointformat{\fbox{\thepoints}}
\question[4] This is Q4 with  marks.
\end{questions}
\gradetable
\end{document}
```

Comment: I need the ```\question``` to remain as is. I noticed that you added `[1]`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why?

Comment: because when I write papers some ```\question``` have points and some don't. But I know at the end of the day, each ```\question``` will have a fixed value of points.

Comment: So basically you would like to say: If there are no points set, set it to x points?

You could define a placeholder variable, e.g. `\newcommand{\nomarks}{1}` and then say `\question[\nomarks] This is Q1 with no marks.`

Comment: But you see, in that case it will force me to manually change each individual ```\question[2 or 3 or 4]``` with points and set them to ```\question[\nopoints]``` where I want to ignore what every is written in ```[ 2,3 or 4 ] ``` and go straight to the grade table and force the question points to be a particular value.